# ggplot iterate several columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, apply, lapply

```
  lapply(7:12, function(x) ggplot(mydf)+geom_histogram(aes(mydf[,x])))
```

will give an error `Error in [.data.frame(mydf, , x) : undefined columns selected`.

I have used several SO questions (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251928/list-of-plots-using-lapply)) as guidance, but can't figure out my error.

Comment: The problem is that `ggplot` doesn't know about `x` when you call it inside of `aes()`.

Comment: Think about the scope of these variables. X is within aes() which is within ggplot() that is within the function().

Comment: @ahburr No, `aes` is evaluated later when x is out of scope.

Comment: You should be using `aes_string(x)` here rather than `aes(mydf[,x])`. Please read up on the differences.

Comment: "ggplot doesn't know about x when you call it inside of aes()" - that means there is a scope issue. Understanding scope of your variables when writing these lines of R code with multiple functions interacting / within each other is often overlooked and easy to mix up. I think the author, @koenbro, may learn a lot from thinking about this problem in terms of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works with the `mtcars` dataset. Just replace `mtcars` with `mydf`.

```
library(ggplot2)
lapply(1:3,function(i) {
  ggplot(data.frame(x=mtcars[,i]))+
    geom_histogram(aes(x=x))+
    ggtitle(names(mtcars)[i])
  })
```

Notice how the reference to `i` (the column index) was moved from the `mapping` argument (the call to `aes(...)`), to the `data` argument.

Your problem is actually quite subtle. `ggplot` evaluates the arguments to `aes(...)` first in the context of your data - e.g. it looks for column names in `mydf`. If that fails it jumps to the *global environment*. It does not look in the function's environment. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287498/scoping-of-variables-in-aes-inside-a-function-in-ggplot) for another example of this behavior and some discussion.

The bottom line is that *it is a really bad idea* to use external variables in a call to `aes(...)`. However, the `data=...` argument does not suffer from this. If you must refer to a column number, etc., do it in the call to `ggplot(data=...)`.